# Livewire - Assigning multiple values through checboxes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I need to add multiple values through checkboxes to the company_user pivot table

This is what i have tried so far

Livewire Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Company;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class UserAssignCompanySection extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $sortBy = 'id';
    public $sortAsc = false;
    public $user;
    public $companies;
    public $search;
    public $confirmingCompanyRemoval = false;
    public $selected = [];

    protected $rules = [
        'user.name' => 'required',
        'user.email' => 'required',
        'user.title' => 'required',
        'user.first_name' => 'required',
        'user.last_name' => 'nullable',
        'user.mobile' => 'nullable',
        'user.phone' => 'nullable',
        'user.is_customer' => 'boolean',
        'user.is_provider' => 'boolean',
    ];

    // Table Sort
    public function sortBy($field)
    {
        if($field == $this->sortBy){
            $this->sortAsc = !$this->sortAsc;
        }
         $this->sortBy = $field;
    }

    public function updatedSelected()
    {
        $this->user->companies()->sync($this->selected);
    }

    public function mount(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->companies = Company::all();
        $this->selected = $this->user->companies->pluck('id')->toArray();
    }

    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.user-assign-company-section');
    }
}
```

```
<div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 text-left xl:grid-cols-6">
        <div class="col-span-3 p-4">
            <p class="text-lg underline">Name</p>
            <x-jet-input wire:model.defer="user.name" id="name" type="text" disabled class="block w-full mt-1 bg-gray-100" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="user.name" class="mt-2" />
            <br>
            <p class="text-lg underline">Assigned Company List</p>
            @json($selected);
            @foreach($companies as $company)
            <div class="mt-1">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $company->id }}" wire:model="selected">
                    {{ $company->name }} <br>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            <br>
            <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}"><x-jet-button>Back</x-jet-button></a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Syncing records to the pivot table doesn't work properly

```
@json($selected)
```

Gives the proper results when the page gets loaded.

When i add a new chckbox, it includes the id of the company as a string **"1"**

@json($selected) shows

```
[2,3,4,"1"]
```

At this moment the new pivot record is been added

Then when i select the back button
@json($selected) shows something like this

```
[2,3,4,1]
```

The back button doesn't take me back(I will be placed on the same page)

Then when it comes to Unchecking. It doesn't work at all
@json($selected) doesn't show sync with unchecked values

Edit :

Company Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Company extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'phone',
        'vat_no',
        'address',
        'is_customer',
        'is_provider',
        'is_self',
    ];

    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }


}
```

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Company;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
    use Historyable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'title',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'mobile',
        'phone',
        'is_customer',
        'is_provider',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class);
    }


}
```

I did this

```
  public function updatedSelected()
    {
        dd($this->user, $this->selected);
        $this->user->companies()->sync($this->selected);
    }
```

and it gives

```
App\Models\User {#1683 ▼
  #fillable: array:10 [▼
    0 => "name"
    1 => "email"
    2 => "password"
    3 => "title"
    4 => "first_name"
    5 => "last_name"
    6 => "mobile"
    7 => "phone"
    8 => "is_customer"
    9 => "is_provider"
  ]
  #hidden: array:4 [▼
    0 => "password"
    1 => "remember_token"
    2 => "two_factor_recovery_codes"
    3 => "two_factor_secret"
  ]
  #casts: array:2 [▼
    "email_verified_at" => "datetime"
    "deleted_at" => "datetime"
  ]
  #appends: array:1 [▼
    0 => "profile_photo_url"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "users"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:26 [▶]
  #original: array:26 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "companies" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1688 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  #forceDeleting: false
  #accessToken: null
}
array:1 [▼
  0 => "1"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function in livewire component, whenever the user click on checkbox you add the value to $selected attribute.

In livewire component(this add/remove company id):

```
public function addCompany($companyId) {
 if (!in_array($companyId, $this->selected)) {
     $this->selected [] = $companyId;
 }else{
     $this->selected = array_diff($this->selected, [$companyId]);
 }
}
```

And in your view add this your input:

```
wire:click="addStyle({{ $collection['id'] }})"
```